# Proper way to set up Semantic UI Modal's Lifecycle with React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

## The problem

Set up proper lifestyle of Semantic UI modal and integrate it with container component.

## Container

My container component is called `NewsList`, it contains a button, which fires up Semantic UI Modal to confirm, that you really want to delete this news.
Modal is created in `onNewsDelete(news)` and stored in container's `state`. Render method checks if `this.state.modal` exists and if so, renders it.

## Modal

First step - to display the modal, works perfectly fine. All job is done inside the `componentDidMount` method, which looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $(this.refs.modal)
      .modal({
        onHidden: this.props.onCancel
      })
      .modal('show')
  }
```

Modal is displayed, and callback to parent method is stored as `onHidden` event callback to destroy the modal after it's been dismissed.

## Back to container

After the modal is dismissed, the parent's callback is invoked (we passed it via `onCancel` prop). There we set container's state to `{ modal: null }` in order to destroy the component. And there's an error:

```
NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

I'm not really sure if it happens because I'm missing something or I just don't understand components' lifecycles at all.

Comment: Probably should avoid using jquery with react. React deals with a virtual dom, and jquery directly changes the DOM which can mess up react if you're not careful. This is a great video which shows how to properly create modals in react: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGjv-p9jYf0

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to avoid mixing jquery with React but the code for `componentDidMount` is literally copy-pasted from [Integrations guide](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/integrations.html). Will check out the video though!